# How to convert std::string to std::u32string?

Tags: c++11, stl, char, stdstring, char32-t

Is there an easy STL way to convert a std::string to a std::u32string, i.e. a basic_string of char to char32_t?

This is not a Unicode question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialise a new string:

```
std::u32string s32(s.begin(), s.end());
```

To assign to an existing string:

```
s32.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

If the string might contain characters outside the supported range of `char`, then this might cause sign-extension issues, converting negative values into large positive values. Dealing with that possibility is messier; you'll have to convert to `unsigned char` before widening the value.

```
s32.resize(s.size());
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s32.begin(), 
               [](char c) -> unsigned char {return c;});
```

or a plain loop

```
s32.clear();  // if not already empty
for (unsigned char c : s) {s32 += c;}
```

Comment: How do I stop the sign-extension in this conversion?

0x80 to 0xff are being converted to 0x80 0xff 0xff 0xff to 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff

Comment: @user3443139: You don't. If the string might contain values outside the well-defined range of `char`, then you'll need to do something more complicated.

Comment: @user3443139: I've added some suggestions to deal with unsupported characters.

Comment: Thanks.  Another possibility is that I switch to using std::basic_string<unsigned char> rather than std::string

Comment: @user3443139: You can try, but it's unsupported. The standard only specifies specialisations of `char_traits` for `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` and `wchar_t`. Your library may or may not have a usable specialisation for `unsigned char`, which may or may not do the right thing. Portably, you'd have to write your own traits class, which is probably more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score -1):

```
s32.resize(s.length());
std::copy(s.begin(),s.end(),s32.begin());
```

Comment: Just a note: it looks better if you use code blocks instead of inline code spans. You can do so by indenting your code by 4 spaces (or highlight all your code and press Ctrl + K).